# JFace Treeviewer refresh produces duplicate rows?

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface

I have a custom treeviewer which extends composite and has treeviewer as the class member, which is hooked up with a content provider, label provider and a sorter. Whenever I sort, 
though the input gets sorted, it produces multiple rows of existing elements.

Has some one encountered the same problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for a bug in your sort implementation and/or your content provider. TreeViewer will only display duplicates if the duplicates are fed to it by the content provider.

Comment: Thanks. There was a bug in the Content Provider. I was recreating elements in the getElements() method.